# Visual Studio 2017 Cordova compilar apk

Tags: visual-studio, apache-cordova

Estou tentando compilar um apk feito com HTML5 no Visual Studio 2017 mas ele simplesmente dá essa mensagem:

```
1>------ Compilação iniciada: Projeto: Relatorios, Configuração: Debug Android ------
Cordova 6.3.1
------ A plataforma android já existe
------ Copiando arquivos nativos de C:\Users\Filipe\source\repos\Relatorios\Relatorios\res\native\android para C:\Users\Filipe\source\repos\Relatorios\Relatorios\platforms\android
------ Cópia dos arquivos nativos para C:\Users\Filipe\source\repos\Relatorios\Relatorios\platforms\android concluída
========== Compilar: 1 com êxito, 0 com falha, 0 atualizados, 0 ignorados ==========
```

Eu segui vários tutoriais na internet inclusive um video do TekZoom, fiz exatamente o mesmo que o tutorial indicava mas o apk nao é gerado. Por que será?

Answer (score -1):

A compilação foi feita com sucesso.
só não sei qual é o tipo de retorno de uma compilação de html5
olhou na pasta Debug do seu projeto o que resultou?

deu uma lida [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31062707/how-to-create-an-apk-of-a-html5-to-run-on-android) ou [aqui](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/)?

Pelo pouco que li na documentação do cordova ele cria uma aplicação que nada mais é do que um html que é executado no browser do seu device

[aqui](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html) tem toda a documentação necessária para se criar algo no cordova

Espero ter ajudado